# Testing an asynchronous function in an angular factory

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise, factory

Im new to testing and im trying to test my angular code in Jasmine. Im stuck on the problem of testing the answer from an resolved promise. Right now the test gets timed out. I would like to have the test waiting for the respons instead of just put in a mockup respons. How do i do that? Is it a bad way of making unit-tests?

```
angular.module("Module1", ['ng']).factory("Factory1", function($q){
    function fn1(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function(){ deferred.resolve(11); }, 100); // this is representing an async action
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    return { func1 : fn1 };
});

describe('test promise from factory', function() {
    var factory1, $rootScope, $q;
    beforeEach(module('Module1'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(Factory1, _$rootScope_, _$q_) {
        factory1=Factory1;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $q = _$q_;
    }));

    it('should be get the value from the resolved promise', function(done) {
        factory1.func1().then(function(res){
            expect(res).toBe(11);
            done(); // test is over
        });

        $rootScope.$digest();
    });
});
```

The setTimeout() block represents an async function call, and i dont want to replace it with something like $timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wouldn't want to use the `$timeout` service.

But if you really want to use the `setTimeout`, a `$rootScope.$digest()` is required inside the callback.

```
function fn1() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  // this is representing an async action
  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve(11);
    $rootScope.$digest(); // this is required ($timeout do this automatically).
  }, 100); 

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: thx for the response, it gave me a clue. I see now that i have to delay the $rootScope.$digest() so it happens after the promise is resolved. Since my real code had lots of promises in it, i found it usefull to set up a timer trigger a couple of those $rootScope.$digest() to make the test work.